# What am I doing wrong ? I want to my spiders crawl to the next page using the URL

Tags: scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I am working on the simple tutorial.
Everything works except that I can't crawl to the next page.

```py
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls=['http://quotes.toscrape.com']
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]

    def parse(self,response):
        for response in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
        yield { 
            "quote":response.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract(),
            "author" : response.xpath('./span/small[@class="author"]/text()').extract(),
            "tag" : response.xpath('./div[@class="tags"]/a/text()').extract()
        }
        next_page = response.xpath('//nav/ul[@class="pager"]/li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

My error message:

> next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
>
> AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'urljoin'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overriding the response object with your for loop. Thus the inner response object in your for loop is just of the type `spidy.language.path_node.PathNode` that does not contain a definition for urljoin. This should solve your problem.

```
for response_path in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
   yield { 
   "quote":response_path.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract(),
        "author" : response_path.xpath('./span/small[@class="author"]/text()').extract(),
        "tag" : response_path.xpath('./div[@class="tags"]/a/text()').extract()
         }
    next_page = response_path.xpath('//nav/ul[@class="pager"]/li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: If i am i correct my issue was that my next_page definition was inside my for loop ?

Comment: Thanks, please mark as answer then. Taking the lines after `next_page = ...` out of the for loop would work as well but would result in a different outcome, that depends on the contents of your response/what you want to do. But my code does not override the response object at all...